# JavaScript - How does Constructor Invocation know how to add "self" variables to returned object?

Tags: javascript

When using constructor function invocation in JavaScript, I have read that the this variable/keyword within the function will be bound to the new object and will return a object that has all the bound "this" values.

For example:

```
function Person() {
  this.name = "bob";
  this.age = 33;
}

var person = new Person(); // person object with name property of "bob" and age property of 33
```

If I do something like this, the same result will occur:

```
function Person() {
  var localVar = "test",
      fake = "fake";
  this.name = "bob";
  this.age = 33;
}

    var person = new Person(); // person object with name property of "bob" and age property of 33 regardless of the local variables declared inside
```

However, if I do something like this, the variables/properties declared on self will return in the object

```
function Person() {
  var self = this;
  self.phone = "123-123-1222";
  self.career = "programmer";
  this.name = "bob";
  this.age = 33;
}

    var person = new Person(); // person object with name property of "bob" and age property of 33, phone of "123-123-1222" and career of "programmer"
```

In the last example, how does the interpreter know to return all four properties, even though two of them are bound to a local variable of this and not the actual "this" keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last example, `self` is just a reference to `this`. They're interchangeable because they point to the same object:

```
function foo() {
    var self = this;
    var that = self;

    console.log(self === this);  // true
    console.log(that === this);  // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because at run time it actually becomes

```
function Person() {
  this.phone = "123-123-1222";
  this.career = "programmer";
  this.name = "bob";
  this.age = 33;
}
```

since 'self' will simply get replaced by 'this'.